# Документирование бизнес-логики и базы данных

Tags: sql-server, документация

Бизнес слой находится в базе в триггерах и процедурах.

**Задача:** Организовать подробное документирование сущностей базы данных а также организовать документирования связанных с этими сущностями бизнес-процессов.

**Что сейчас?**
Сейчас документирование хранимых процедур и триггеров происходит посредством одного большого коммента в начале, описывающего всю историю изменений и куча комментов внутри процедуры. Сущности базы данных, такие как таблицы, вьюхи, и т.д., документируются с помощью Extended properties.

Всё это дело бывает не всегда удобным. Точнее почти никогда. Хочется чтобы где-то хранилось единое описание безнес-процесса и к этому описанию были привязаны сущности базы данных с подробным документированием.

**Вопрос в том** - как это документирование организовать. Если вы не знаете прямого ответа на вопрос, то ,возможно, вы сможете поделиться тем как у вас ведется документирование базы данных. Это тоже будет полезно. Спасибо.

Comment: Вот вчера ссылка попалась [Auto Generate Your Database Documentation](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Extended+Property/137761/), и там рядом [Industrial-strength database documentation using Extended Properties](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Metadata/72610/). Но скорее всего ничего нового для вас. Я просмотрел бегло, там так же документирование всего через extended properties (включая stored procs).